# Prevent access to php pages

Tags: php, file, .htaccess

Ok, so I have set the .htaccess like so:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ index.php
```

so as you can see I'm parsing everything to index except files because I need to "include" the php files and also displaying of images.

If users will type for example www.site.com/login.php that will show the login php page.

How do I prevent access to the php pages but also allow to "include" them?

Comment: Files do not need to be web-accessible via the web server to be included by PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Move them outside of your document root. They can be safely included from there but not accessed over the web.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question do you want to not allow the user to go to other files if not logged in ? If so you can use php sessions to set a variable that they are logged in otherwise redirect to index

(If I understand the question)

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna go that route (the outside webroot advise is the correct one!) then you could use a rule like that (see [regex negative lookahead](http://www.google.com/search?q=regex%20negative%20lookahead)):

```
 RewriteRule ^(?!index).+\.php$ - [F]
```

That's sloppy in that would allow `index2.php` or `indexdir/xyz.php` still; it just pevents anything that's not `index`*`.php` from being accessed. Make sure to also disallow `.cgi` or `.phtml` or `.tpl` if need be.

Comment: Actually would be simpler with making your current index.php rule `[L]` last, and disallowing just `\.php$` with `[F]` in a fallback rule behind that.